# RealTime web app with PouchDB

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am writing a real time web app with pouchdb. I am currently using vanilla pouchdb on top of backbone.

That being said, I have been running into **quite a bit of conflicts** and was wondering if you have any suggestions as to how to handle pouchdb conflicts in the context of a real time web app?

Also, I've noticed this plugin:
https://github.com/redgeoff/delta-pouch. How would this plugin assist with real time web apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delta-pouch will give you a setup where there are no conflicts at all, as long as you can express every change as a delta (i.e. a change that is not dependent on a previous state, such as a transaction to a bank account that adds $50).

You can also use this project to assist in resolving conflicts: https://github.com/jo/pouch-resolve-conflicts Or read the guide to conflicts: http://pouchdb.com/guides/conflicts.html

Comment: Do you know if delta-pouch is compatible with websocket sync solutions for pouchdb? (https://github.com/pgte/pouch-websocket-sync, https://github.com/nolanlawson/socket-pouch)